# Make area chart from SCL band of Sentinel 2 in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to calculate areas of classes available in SCL band. But Earth Engine is giving some weighted average error.

Script Link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/1bfc6233a6cea1eb57db0513449e1624
Script:

```
var image = ic.filterBounds(geometry).filterDate('2023-02-01','2023-04-09').mean();
Map.addLayer(image.clip(geometry),{min:4200,max:7500, bands:['B4','B3','B2']},"Image")
Map.addLayer(image.select('SCL'),{min:1,max:11},'SCL');

// generating chart
var scl = image.select('SCL');

var chart = ui.Chart.image.byClass({
  image: (ee.Image.pixelArea().multiply(scl)).divide(1e6),
  classBand:'SCL',
  region: geometry,
  reducer:ee.Reducer.sum().group(1),
  scale:50
})
print(chart)
```

The Following error shows up:

```
Error generating chart: Reducer.forEach: Can't repeat Reducer.group(Reducer.sum) (only some of its inputs are weighted).
```